# Sitecore Upgrade from 8.1 update-3 to 9.1

Tags: upgrade

Reference link for additional context: [Sitecore upgrade from 8.1 Update-3 to 9 Update-1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/sitecore-upgrade-from-8-1-update-3-to-9-update-1/15360?noredirect=1#comment23398_15360)

@JayS: Regarding Sitecore Upgrade from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.1, as suggested by you I am setting up a new instance of Sitecore 9.1 and upgrading the database of the existing website and after than I will point the new application to upgraded DB.

I have one question regarding upgrade of database: First we have to Execute scripts for the Core, Master, and Web databases (execute the `CMS_core.sql` script for the Core database only) and after this I have to install the upgrade package using the Sitecore Update Installation Wizard. In the wizard, on the Analyse package page do we have to select only 'Install Items' and unchecked 'Install Files' as we are using fresh installation?

Comment: To clarify, which version of Sitecore are you upgrading to? 9.1 (as you state in your question), or 9.0 Update-1 (as you reference in the linked question)?

Comment: backup your web folders. Run the upgrade, restore your folders back.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it doesn't matter. If you are performing the database upgrade using an instance of Sitecore that is already on the upgraded version, updating the files will have no effect because they will simply be replaced by the same files.

Comment: I agree with @DanSinclair.  When I upgraded from 8.1 to 8.2, I did that exact same procedure and I did not encounter any issues.  I have not done an upgrade to 9.x (but will be in the next month or 2) but based on past experience, I intend to follow that same method.

Comment: I am planning to perform only database upgrade (using sitecore installation wizard) in the existing application which is running on Sitecore 8 update 1, once database upgraded will be completed successfully then we will set up a fresh Sitecore 9.1 instance and re point our database to upgraded one and copy patch from old instance and paste it in the new one. Could you please let me know if this approach looks fine to you.

Comment: Yes, it seems fine to me. I would recommend taking database backups beforehand just in case.